# Kendo treelist dropdown not listing values in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, kendo-ui

I have created a kendo treelist dropdown.
But the dropdown is not getting populated with values in IE 11.
It works fine with chrome.
When I click on the dropdown, just a blank dropdown appears.
Please help!

Comment: I have found that IE tends to cache the results for tree node population "aggressively".  So I wouldn't be surprised it IE is caching your very first call to your action where you returned zero nodes.  I always have to put [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]  (ASP.NET MVC)on my controller action that returns the tree nodes to get it to work in IE...oops just saw that it is not a TreeVIew...my comment may still be relevant and IE may be caching when you think it is not.

Comment: I am using selectpicker dropdown